# Is it annoying if people create new accounts for asking questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, new-users

Lately I've noticed that many people are creating new SO accounts to ask questions. Maybe because they are afraid of getting downvoted for the question on their actual account, or maybe they don't want dumb questions to appear on their profile.

Watching SO for new questions, 3-4 questions out of 10 are by a new user who has 1 reputation, and the question structure proves that this user has a good knowledge of question asking concepts, which proves that the user is not actually new to SO.

Does it seem annoying to you? Maybe SO needs to do something with these people? For example, at least answer 1-2 questions before you post your own question?

Comment: Someone being able to ask a good question doesn't mean they are familiar with [so].

Comment: 1) Writing a good question isn't *proof* that they're an experienced SO user.  Evidence, sure, proof, certainly not.  2) How is this behavior problematic?  In what way would the site be better if users always asked questions from the account that they answered on?  As you said, they're asking great questions.  Why do we want to discourage people asking *great* questions?

Comment: Maybe some of these users actually read the FAQ and looked at other questions to determine how to post. Seems a little unfair to say: "your question is too good! Burn the witch!"

Comment: i don't believe SO gets 5-10 new users in every minute and each of them post a new question.

Comment: I've seen the same question being asked by multiple "users." Seemed legit.

Comment: So you just assume that every user with 1 reputation who happen to ask a good question is an experienced user with another high rep account? Sorry, but I totally disagree with such assumption.

Comment: SO is not a regular forum. first time users need some time to get familiar to ask questions in the right way in SO.

Comment: @Zafar Doesn't seem hard to believe to me.  There are a lot of programmers.  There are a lot of programmers that have questions for other programmers.  Sure, some of them will have other accounts, but not a huge percentage.  Most that have another account are likely people who asked one or two other questions, discarded the account, and didn't remember the credentials.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian Question bans span more than just an account.  Also, users trying to dodge question bans through multiple accounts, if caught, will have their accounts merged.  Regardless, this particular question is about high rep users asking great questions, so they clearly won't be risking question bans.

Comment: @Zafar And people can get that experience from lurking, not just answering.  Some people are also just generally good at asking questions, take time trying to solve their own problems before asking about them on a public q/a site, know that improving the quality of their question improves the likelihood of answers and their quality, etc.  You don't *need* to be a high rep user who answers a lot of questions to ask a good question.

Comment: So long as the person is not trying to circumvent a posting ban, a suspension, or participating in voter fraud, there is nothing wrong with having multiple accounts.

Comment: There are a lot of programmers who have been reading SO questions for years because they found them via Google, and never needed to ask a question yet because they always found the answer via Google.

Answer (score 11):

> In last times I've noticed that many people are creating new SO
>   accounts to ask questions. May be because either they are afraid of
>   getting downvoted for the question on their actual account, or they
>   don't want dumb questions to appear on their profile.

This isn't a problem in and of itself. If people want to opt out of the whole reputation system thats fine (posting poor content is a problem, but thats a seperate issue)

> Watch out the SO for new question, 3-4 questions out of 10 is by a new
>   user who has 1 reputation, and the question structure proves that this
>   user has a good knowledge of question asking concepts, which proves
>   that uses is not actually new to SO.

Some of these users may actually read the FAQ and have looked at other questions to determine how to post. Or they may be familiar with other high quality sites, they are out there. It seems like a huge leap to say that good first posts are evidence of secret accounts.

> Does it seem annoying to you? May be SO need to do something with
>   these people? For example, at least answer 1-2 questions before you
>   post your own question?

This was the part that prompted me to post an answer. This would lead to people who don't want to answer answering, just to get their question asked. This would lead to desperate guesses instead of answers. Lowering the quality of the site. (Or more likely; a dramatic reduction in the numbers of new users)

An even worse possibility if that people may start writing follow up questions *as* answers since they can't start their own questions. Questions as answers is bad enough as it is, we don't want to encourage it further

Comment: You, SE said to me that's not possible to create a second account. "no, don't do it". But if the system isn't perfect and I'm banned forever? To lift a ban, how, what to do..

Comment: @xsi bans can be lifted by improving existing content and getting upvotes. Are you currently banned or is this hypothetical?

Answer (score 5):

I think you're making a lot of assumptions and jumping to unnecessary conclusions here. Primarily that users new to Stack Overflow must also be too stupid to ask a good question on their first try, so these new users asking good questions must not be new users after all. I don't know how or why you would even want to make such an assumption.

I also don't know what's annoying about this - who cares if a user creates a separate account to ask a question? Does it really matter who's asking the question? Why? Either you can answer the question or not, and either it's a good question or it isn't. Good questions are great for the site, regardless of who asked them; bad questions get closed, because they're not good for the site, again regardless of who asked.

I disagree that there is any reason to force users to *answer* questions before they're allowed to ask their own questions. I don't even know where to start with that. Most people find this site for the first time because they have a question to ask, not because they have a sudden need to participate in a community and earn reputation for good answers and then finally earn the right to think about some questions to ask.

Answer (score 3):

The assumption that (good question + low rep) == (sock puppet account!) doesn't necessarily hold true.  I asked my highest-voted question in my first month on SO.

But for the sake of argument, let's say you're right.  Let's say that 5000 times a day, high-rep members have a question they'd be embarrassed to ask on their main account.  Even though it's a good question, they don't want to admit ignorance about a given subject.

So what?

As long as the question is good, why should it matter who's asking?